# Firebase конфликтует с gms:play-services, как разрешить проблему?

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services

> All gms/firebase libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 9.6.0, 11.8.0. Examples include `com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.0` and `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0`

Firebase конфликтует с `gms:play-services`, как разрешить проблему?

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.hr"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
}




apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Методом тыка нашел конфликт, может кому поможет в будущем
Проблема была в `com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth`, обновил до версии 3.1.3 и конфликт пропал